# Peity chart plugin gradient colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I use a small plugin called Peity for bar like charts in my template that converts an array of numbers into an svg image. It's easy to change the background color of bars according to documentation:

```
$.fn.peity.defaults.bar = {
  fill: ["#4d89f9"]
}
```

**Is it possible to turn a background color into a gradient?**

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463979/how-to-give-a-polygon-a-gradient-fill-inside-a-svg

Comment: Surely that's the actual answer!